# How to get rows in Postgres with hstore values fulfilling certain condition returning the keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I have hstore column. Now I want to filter on rows that fulfill a certain criteria for the hstore values - not knowing the keys. 
E.g.

```
hstore column 'attributes': aspect1=3, aspect2=0, aspect3=1, aspect4=0
```

Now I want to fetch all rows with hstore values = 0. And list the keys.

Answer (score 1):

1st transform hstore entries to rows in a CTE:

```
with aspects as (select ..., (each("attributes")).*
    from mainTable),
```

The each() function gives you 2 columns named 'key' and 'value'.
Now use this CTE with the desired condition, joining to the main table and collect the keys back as array:

```
select ..., array_agg(key) as fulfilled_aspects
    from aspects a join mainTable m on m.id = a.id
    where a.value = '0'
```

And the result would be a row with 'fulfilled_aspects' array column containing:
**'aspect2, aspect4'**

You can also use the latter as CTE to add further columns from the mainTable to the result.